# Limelight - Read timed out

Tags: raspbian, connection

I'm trying to set up "Embedded" implementation of Limelight on my Raspberry Pi Model B. https://github.com/irtimmer/limelight-embedded

The Raspberry Pi seems to be functioning properly, I've installed Raspbian, and transferred the limelight jar to the machine. I successfully paired limelight with my desktop computer.

The problem I'm getting is that whenever I try to start the stream I get a "Read timed out" error.

In general the Raspberry Pi seems to be able to connect to the internet just fine (via an ethernet cable). I've used the network connection to download a few libraries (namely xboxdrv and also to update the raspberry pi firmware).

I've tried reinstalling NVIDIA GeForce Experience (which handles "GameStream"). I tried updating the raspberry pi. But I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to troubleshoot this. Can anyone with a bit more experience give me some pointers on what the problem might be or how to go about debugging it?

```
Starting Steam
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:235)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:153)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:169)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:119)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:134)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:314)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:233)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:84)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.http.NvHTTP.openHttpConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.http.NvHTTP.openHttpConnectionToString(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.http.NvHTTP.getServerInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.NvConnection.startApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.NvConnection.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.NvConnection.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.NvConnection$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Read timed out
Connection Error Starting Steam failed
```

Occasionally I also get a "handshake_failure" error instead.

```
Starting Steam
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1991)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1104)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:235)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:153)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:169)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:119)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:134)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:314)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:233)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:84)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.http.NvHTTP.openHttpConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.http.NvHTTP.getAppList(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.http.NvHTTP.getApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.NvConnection.startApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.NvConnection.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.NvConnection.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at com.limelight.nvstream.NvConnection$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Connection Error Starting Steam failed
```

---

**Update**: I made some more attempts, and I've been able to stream the game Child of Light. However, the problem persists for Steam. Perhaps this is an issue with Steam itself, but I'm led to believe that other people are able to stream Steam Big Picture just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using the most recent build of Limelight-Embedded. I have had success with this, but it isn't perfect by any stretch! Your most likely problem (excluding networking issues) is a mismatch of Limelight version and GeForce Experience.

You need to make sure you have the most current GeForce Experience (2.2.2 as I write this) - install, then make sure to check for updates within the program. If your graphics card driver needs an update do that too, just in case.

I used a current image of Raspian to start, fully updated with both *apt-get upgrade* and *rpi-update*. I had done a lot of other messing around, but nothing that affects Limelight.

Run the *pair* option again (*java -jar limelight.jar pair* [your pc ip]) after deleting the existing pairing files (client.crt and a couple of others - basically you want nothing but the limelight.tar and libopus.so in the directory, unless you've built yourself a shell script to run or something like that)

If you pair successfully try *java -jar limelight.jar stream* [your pc ip]

**One note** - don't forget the *libopus.so* from the GitHub release page @ https://github.com/irtimmer/limelight-embedded/releases for a substantial performance boost according to the readme. It helps with the audio decompression by switching to hardware floating point calculations I believe.

I hope this is helpful to you and you get up and running! It is good fun, albeit a bit frustrating to get going the first time.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and help, but unfortunately I've already taken all the steps that you mentioned above.

Comment: Apologies, I cannot respond via comment on your original post due to low reputation at this time. Steam Big Picture is not currently functional via Limelight (although not with the errors you have mentioned, it simply does not load in correctly, you just get bubbles on your screen).

EDIT: To continue, it is best to launch games directly at this time.